# PHP date() getting wrong time

Tags: php, datetime, date, timezone

i'm simply trying to get the current date in PHP, but it's getting '07:45:23' when it's really 11:02am (the date part of it is correct). i am setting the timezone like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); 
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

why isn't this working? i also tried 'EDT'. and if it matters, the server is also in the same timezone.

thanks.

Comment: one possibility is that your server clock might be off... is your server linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server's time is likely incorrect. If you have SSH access, running `date` will show you what the server is set to.

Comment: yes, that was the issue. solved by running: date --set='Wed Dec 15 02:00:00 EST 2010' . thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is the servers time set properly?

Comment: Eh, the answer is implied in the post.

Comment: @ceejayoz technically, the answer is a question